# Unity WWW request can i use more then one?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, web, unity-game-engine

I have following code in game. The game checks the winner and loser and send the values to the database. The problem now is, that the game only calls 1 WWW Request wiich is strange.

```
if (playerDataScript.playerTeam == playerStScript.playerTeam)
        {
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(loseClip);
            Debug.Log ("You Lost");
                okayButton.SetActive (true);
                WWWForm form1 = new WWWForm ();
                form1.AddField ("user", PlayerPrefs.GetString (LoginSystem.Settings.accountKey.ToString ()));
                form1.AddField ("lose", "1");
                form1.AddField ("gold", Random.Range(50,71));
                form1.AddField("rating", Random.Range(17,31)); // Minus
                WWW saveData1 = new WWW ("http://81.169.176.129/datasavelose.php",form1);
                yield return saveData1;
        }
        else
        {
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(winClip);
                okayButton.SetActive (true);
                WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
                form.AddField ("user", PlayerPrefs.GetString (LoginSystem.Settings.accountKey.ToString ()));
                form.AddField ("win", "1");
                form.AddField ("gold", Random.Range(60,81));
                form.AddField("rating", Random.Range(17,31)); // plus
                WWW saveData = new WWW ("http://81.169.176.129/datasave.php",form);
                yield return saveData;
        }
```

My question: can i use 2 WWW Request with 2 different php files in the same script?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do multiple WWW requests at once.

Are you sure it is getting into the else block? (That, and that you are calling it more than once!)

Most of the time it's the little things that trip me up :)

Comment: Yes its a Win/Lose function. the else block is when the player wins. But also when the player wins its calling the lose function and saves the lose details in the database at only one player.

Comment: I understand how you want it to work, I was just saying are you sure the method is getting called like you planned. It sounds like it is not.